# Loading an excel workbook in R mac

Tags: r, excel

In order to install the "XLConnect" in R on my mac, I did the following:

```
install.packages("rjava") 
install("XLConnect")
```

Then to load an excel Workbook,

```
loadWorkbook(filename,create=T)
```

But it gives me

> $\color{red}{Error in path.expand(filename) : object 'filename' not found}$

Can someone help. I apologise for my editing, I am new to this.

Comment: Did you make an object called `filename`? If not, that might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Seems your filename was not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Furthermore: Instead of using `XLConnect`, you might want to check the `openxlsx`-package. It doesn't depend on java and is in my experince faster and more stable.

Comment: I also switched from XLconnect to openxlsx due to java problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when it comes to R the difference between MAC and Windows are small. You have been presented for *XLConnect* and *open.xlsx*. I do not like XLConnect because I have had problems when reading in a lot of excel files as a result of the Java memory capacity. I do like *readxl* which does the job.

```
if(!require("readxl")) install.packages("readxl",dependencies = TRUE);library("readxl")
df<-read_excel(path = path, sheet = "sheetname in excel file")
df<-as.data.frame(df) #Because it does not read in as a data frame
```